# how to measure the time taken to bubble sort 10 numbers

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I am trying to measure the time it takes to bubble sort 10 large numbers. I put the numbers in an array of size 10. Then, I am bubble sorting the numbers 10 times and printing out the time taken for each time.

The problem is that all im getting is zeros for some reason!

Here is what i have in the main:

```
 int n = sizeof(arr10)/sizeof(arr10[0]);
            start=clock();
            bubbleSort(arr10, n);
            end=clock();
            cpu_time_used = (double) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            printf("Bubble Sort time= %f\n",cpu_time_used);
```

and here is the function of bubble sort:

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)

    // Last i elements are already in place
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
```

Comment: try printing start and end. what does clock() return? If everything is ok, then do the devision.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is the array hardcoded? It is possible that the compiler just throws away the whole sorting since no output depends on it.

Comment: A more appropriate measure, in many ways, is to count the number of swaps. Crudely you can do that using a global variable.

Comment: Mesuring the sorting an array of length 10 is probably pointless because it's too fast to be mesurable.

Comment: The time required to sort 10 numbers, even with a bubble sort, is smaller than the granularity of `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.  To get measurable times you’ll either need to use a larger array or sort the smaller array multiple times.

Comment: what is the datatype of start ,end and cpu_time_used ?

Comment: A guess is that the correct time is about 0.00000001 seconds, and you cannot measure that with enough precision.

Comment: @recycler yes both start and end are zeros!! why is that?

Comment: @AlbinPaul double.

Comment: I ran the code on Ubuntu and actually got values!

Comment: @M.Hamra because clock() uses kernel functions which update internal variables slower than your sort run. normally you should run the sorting 10^6 or 10^9 times and average the results.

Answer (score 2):

That the result is zero is probaby because the resolution of `clock()` is too low. There are `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` ticks, and `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1000. Your example probably runs in less than 1000th of a second (less than 1 millisecond).

Comment: Yeah, OP needs some more '0's.  More values, more sorts. 100/100, maybe.

Comment: What do you suggest? and can I change CLOCKS_PER_SEC?

Comment: Loop a million times. And no, you can't change CLOKS_PER_SEC. That is the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%e` format specifier to print the seconds. What is most likely happening is that the number is so small that `%f` just prints `0`.

Anyway regardless of how you print it, the results are pretty much useless, as such a small time will not be relevant for measuring your algorithm, other noise in the OS will dominate.

Measuring the sort time of 10 numbers will never yield any significant value. Try with thousands and millions of numbers. And don't forget to compile with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Yes it is so small even when i use %e it still prints out zeros!